# OpenSource API in Java for Two RTF file Comparison

Tags: java, rtf

I found Aspose,iTextRTF resources.
Aspose is not open source.
iTextRTF cant find jar containing RtfWriter2..?
Does jRTF resource compare RTF files..?
Your Help is highly appreciated.Thanx in advance.

Comment: What exactly would you like to compare? Only text or also embedded objects like images and sound? Should the formatting of the text be the same or can that be neglected? What about the output; only a yes/no answer if the files are the same or not, or output each line that is different?

Comment: Only text, formatting of the text be the same

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no free library that supports this. But it may not be that hard to create a basic compare function yourself. You can read in an rtf file and then extract the text like this:

```
// read rtf from file
JEditorPane p = new JEditorPane();
p.setContentType("text/rtf");
EditorKit rtfKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
rtfKit.read(new FileReader(fileName), p.getDocument(), 0);
rtfKit = null;

// convert to text
EditorKit txtKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/plain");
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
txtKit.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0, p.getDocument().getLength());
String documentText = writer.toString();
```

Use `text/plain` in the 2nd editor kit to extract text only (without formatting) and `text/html` to extract text preserving (most of) the formatting. The editor kit will ignore any images, so you do not have to worry about that.
Do this for the two files and then simply compare the resulting html or text of the two files.